# What are the chase lights under Star Trek viewscreens for?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

Under the viewscreen on many Federation starships, there are a series of lights that constantly run through a chase or 'marching ants' pattern.  What's the reason for these lights?  Are they status indicators or some part of the viewscreen projection system?

Comment: I believe they are an intricate artistic methodology referred to by the specialists as "oooouuuu SHINY"

Comment: I always thought they were indicators - at least on the original series - of something having to do with the sensors, indicating they were operating; I have no particular information to back up that theory though.

Comment: Those are Blinkenlights http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights (How to add links in comments?)

Comment: @user1129682 [Looky here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37758/209507)

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish thanks buddy, after half a decade i finally figured it out by myself. but thanks for caring!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the ([Paramount-approved](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_McMaster)) [McMaster Bridge Blueprints](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/mcmaster-uss-enterprise-bridge-blueprints.php), the lights *under* the TOS viewscreen relate to the ship's sensors, presumably confirming that the viewer is working correctly.

[image]

As to their purpose in TNG, the simple truth seems to be that they're utterly useless and exist solely to create a mental linkage between TOS and TNG for fans

> *"While creating these designs with Herman Zimmerman, we heard a
> tremendous amount of angst among the fans that we were 'replacing
> their [original] show,'" Probert says. "So **I included clues that
> hopefully would calm their concerns." Those clues include chasing
> lights below the viewscreen, and a ship's diagram and dedication
> plaque similar to those from TOS.** "Instead of being at the back of the
> bridge, they're on either side, near the front," he adds. "Just above
> the food replicators — which were never used."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: The Next Generation 365](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_365)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 12):

Almost everyone looks towards the main viewscreen, so it's almost certainly all about **Red Alert**.  A whole bunch of other unnecessary/unused lights on the bridge also exist that only turn on during emergencies:

[image: RedAlert on the Bridge]
(Actually, the one above the door may usually be on, but without a color tint.  I just quickly circled some Red Alert lights from TNG 1x21, [The Arsenal of Freedom](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Arsenal_of_Freedom_(episode)))

I have no doubt those running lights do the same.  There *could* be some important extra information conveyed through them (perhaps it's a battery meter for antimatter reserves?), but I don't recall the lights ever actually being mentioned in the series.

Comment: I take it NOBODY who designed the Enterprise ever read Three-Mile Island postmortem report?

Comment: @DVK Nor do I know what you're referring to...

Comment: If I recall correctly, they found that the  Three Mile Island Nuclear Reactor Accedent was at least in part caused by HCI design flaws, including "too many indicators".

Comment: In other words, Don't Design Your Warship Or Nuclear Plant Like It's A Geocities Page lesson of design.

Comment: @DVK Ahh...  In that case, I must disagree.  [It looks like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident#Human_factors_.E2.80.93_confusion_over_valve_status) there were too many _different_ indicators, and one that was particularly badly designed, that appeared to be giving conflicting information.  Star Trek's Red Alert lights are all over the ship, but have exactly one meaning - the ship is in danger.  It's a good way to make sure _everyone_ knows to get to safety, and stay there.

Comment: True, not an EXACT parallel, but close. Typically, when you're doing something useful undrer stress, having a Big Red Flashing Red Alert Light coming at you from 360 degrees is a wee bit distracting :)

Comment: @DVK Picard would agree, when it's tense enough.  In one episode, he practically yelled at the rest of the bridge crew to turn it off (and it was turned off, AFAIR only on the bridge)  =P

Comment: Does anyone know if it turns yellow or red during those alerts?  If that's the case, it sounds like a good answer.

Comment: @BobWarwick: Yes, it does turn to other colours. IIRC, there is red, yellow, blue and grey alert. Indicated by the same panels. Edit: I just [checked](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Alert_signal), these are the conditions that exist.

Comment: @bitmask I have no memory of any lights turning yellow under yellow alert...  Although that could have just been because yellow is faint against white light.  Grey mode does have the lights lowered, though.  But can you confirm for certain that the main viewscreen running lights also change?  (I would've included a picture of that in the answer if I found it; I can get one if you know of an episode where it was shown)

Comment: @Izkata: I don't remember any particular episode, where the view screen lights were yellow, sorry.

Comment: @DVK Don't you think your ref to geocities homepages is even less likely to get than your reference to the Three Mile Island think. I like it though :)

Comment: I could most definitely be wrong about this, but I figured that those light displays were actually "full" terminals, so that people could drop what they're doing and do "red alert" stuff from anywhere.  If you're on the bridge, it makes sense to get to your post, though.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it was my belief that in the original series (TOS), the chase lights have 2 modes. The first one being 2 lights next to each other - alternating left and right, and the more common line left to right. In Star Trek IV it switches to the format we see today. In TNG, DS9 and VOYAGER they are the equivalent to the CPU lights on a modern PC. Note that in Star Trek IV and later that only have one mode: 2 lights moving outwards towards the middle.  Note that Voyager has 2 sets of chase lights: one under the view screen and one above the view screen.

[image]

In the unaired pilot of TOS, it had this view screen
[image]

And here is the NX-01 view screen
[image]

And in the JJ Abrams reboot, they don't even have chase lights.
[image]

Comment: That's because in the reboot lens flare takes the place of chase lights.